Unable to load schema from '/Users/myname/.vscode/extensions/salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-core-61.12.0/node_modules/@salesforce/schemas/[see post]
I'm trying to create a Scratch Org from a modified project-scratch-def.json file in VSCode.
I can't save the changes to the json file because I'm getting the error:
Unable to load schema from '/Users/myname/.vscode/extensions/salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-core-61.12.0/node_modules/@salesforce/schemas/project-scratch-def.schema.json': ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/myname/.vscode/extensions/salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-core-61.12.0/node_modules/@salesforce/schemas/project-scratch-def.schema.json'.
Here is the project-scratch-def.json
{
  "orgName": "myname company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi"],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true,
      "enableLightningPreviewPref": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
  }
}

I have tried reinstalling node, reinstalling the Salesforce Extension Pack, reinstalling Salesforce CLI, rebooting the machine, reloading VSCode, recreating the project, deleting existing scratch orgs, and everything short of sacrificing a chicken in the full moonlight.
If I visit /Users/myname/.vscode/extensions/salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-core-61.12.0/node_modules -- there is no @salesforce directory there.

Someone had a similar problem and apparently my suggestion to downgrade helped - see the comments. Maybe someone should create a ticket for Salesforce to make them aware of the problem.

Thanks! My colleague was able to fix it by doing some sort of re-install of some of the components (maybe the Salesforce extension to vscode?). I had inadvertently installed to a wrong path, or not the default, anyway. We were in a rush at the end of a workday, so I didn't collect good notes on what he did, unfortunately. But it makes sense that a downgrade or upgrade or any kind of reinstall would fix it.
